# "extends keyof" becomes "never" in CallableFunction.call

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The type of the second parameter (`loadingName`) of the following method is the key of the first parameter.

```js
(alias) function withLoading<T, P extends keyof T>(this: T, loadingName: P, before: () => Promise<any>): Promise<void>
import withLoading
```

However, when I call `withLoading.call`, the type of `loadingName` becomes `never`:

```js
(method) CallableFunction.call<this, [loadingName: never, before: () => Promise<any>], Promise<void>>(this: (this: this, loadingName: never, before: () => Promise<any>) => Promise<...>, thisArg: this, loadingName: never, before: () => Promise<any>): Promise<...>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the interest of reducing this to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), let's say you have the following function `func`:

```
declare function func<T>(this: T, key: keyof T): void;
```

You would like to be able to call it as follows, but it doesn't work:

```
func.call({ a: 123 }, "a") // error?!
// CallableFunction.call<{ a: number; }, [key: never], void>(...);
```

Why?

---

You are combining two [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) functions and hoping that the compiler can infer a higher-order relationship between them so that the resulting behavior propagates the generic type parameters from one function to the other without specifying them first.

This isn't a completely crazy thing to hope for, since TypeScript 3.4 introduced some support for [higher order type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions), and TypeScript 3.5 introduced [similar support for generic constructors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-constructors).

Indeed, if you had a standalone function `call()` with no [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types), things would work as desired:

```
declare function call<T, A extends any[], R>(
  thisArg: T, cb: (this: T, ...args: A) => R, ...args: A): R;
call({ a: 123 }, func, "a") // okay
call({ a: 123 }, func, "b") // error
```

So why doesn't it work with a `this` parameter?

---

The short but possibly unsatisfying answer is that the support for higher order function inference is heuristic in nature, and does not work in situations which were not explicitly implemented.  As mentioned in [microsoft/TypeScript#30215](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215), the pull request implementing this support:

> The above algorithm is not a complete unification algorithm and it is by no means perfect.

And while full unification, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134), might be helpful, it would require quite a change to the way type inference currently works in TypeScript and might possibly be problematic in terms of compiler performance.  For now anyway, we have an imperfect-but-performant algorithm.

---

While researching this, I noticed the existence of [microsoft/TypeScript#33139](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33139), a pull request that claims to make such inference work for `this` parameters.  I have not tested it myself, so I can't be sure if it does what it claims.  And while it seems to be assigned to the lead language architect, it's been sitting for quite a while with no change to it.  Usually pull requests are supposed to be linked to particular bug report or feature request issues, but I don't see that here.

---

So what can be done?  The immediate workaround would be to manually specify the generic type parameters yourself, as in:

```
func.call<{ a: number }, [key: keyof { a: number }], void>({ a: 123 }, "a"); // okay
```

It's not great to have to do that, but at least the compiler can *recognize* that such type parameter specifications work for `func.call`... which is definitely better than nothing.  In other words, you don't have to resort to unsafe [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) here.

In the longer term, you might want to comment on [microsoft/TypeScript#30215](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215) to say why a full unification algorithm would improve things.  Someone might also think about filing a separate feature request to extend the TypeScript 3.4 support for higher-order functions to include `this` parameters, and link in there to [microsoft/TypeScript#33139](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33139).  Neither of these steps are guaranteed to have any effect on when or if things will change, but it probably wouldn't hurt.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2&ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=85#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVLTAB4AVAPgAoMALLAZwC54SAaeAaxAE8nOudEzAJRMAbjizAA3ACgZKdADowUCBAoBveFCYBGAEwBmeAF82AIijmh8APS34IGDBwwA-AEIZ9+AGFV0ABGECAAYoTYeMoBRFo68KjIALaBTlKmbADafEyoIKJOALps4pKUihVCsjKgkLAICpi4+CpqpGwAgo4AHhggqMB02qhcmcXwAEqUNPQdMADmTKzwYIFMVLSMzGwVirDzWx02ALxkkzsV+4cik7Kt6nF6RhkE6BZWNj447FBcMveabRPYxmV5gCyBax2BxOFwwOSNaJtR4JZKpGAvbLcXjcATwFGJFJOUzjUrASgogwg97WdJfH5cIA)